# Is this enough background for Spivak?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

I've been doing basic mathematics by serge lang,and recently completed it. I did all the exercises given in the book(except for the chapter on Isometries). I've also done Gelfand's Algebra, Method of the co-ordinates and now I'm planning to do his trigonometry book.

I wanted to know if this much background would be enough to start the calculus book by spivak, i.e. will I be able to follow through the book with this much background knowledge or do I need to do more precalculus books?

If I need to do more study of precalculus topics,then can you please be specific as to what I need to more,and some book recommendations for the same would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have done Lang and Gelfand, why do you need Spivak?

Comment: @JCAA I wanted to learn calculus

Comment: Yes, if you can handle Lang & Gelfand you can certainly handle Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: @copper.hat ok,thanks!

Comment: Can I ask if Lang's Basic Mathematics and Gelfand's Algebra alone would be enough for Spivak? I'm relearning math as an adult. I've decided to read proof books, then do Basic Mathematics, see if I can do Gelfand's Algebra, then try to jump into Spivak.